# How to present ViewController in modaly swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift4

How can i present viewController in modal. am a new beginner in ios and am using swift4
I try this

```
 let userVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
  "menuC") as! MenuController
    userVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
      userVC.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = 
    UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    present(userVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 10):

Do like this

```
if let presentedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuC") {
        presentedViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        presentedViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
        presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext;
        presentedViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.8)
        self.present(presentedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```